# Java/Jersey2/HK: Just in time injection resolver not working

Tags: java, jersey, hk2

I am trying to implement a JIT resolver for Jersey 2.27 and HK, because I don't want to add all of my DAO subclasses to my abstract binder manually. This is my current implementation:

TestService:

```
@Path("test")
public class TestService {

    @Inject
    TestDAO testDAO; // this should be auto injected

    @GET
    public String test() {
        return testDAO.test();
    }
}
```

JITResolver:

```
@Service
@Singleton
@Visibility(DescriptorVisibility.LOCAL)
public class JITResolver implements JustInTimeInjectionResolver {

    @Inject
    ServiceLocator serviceLocator;

    @Override
    public boolean justInTimeResolution(Injectee injectee) {
        Type type = injectee.getRequiredType();
        if (type instanceof Class) {
            Class<?> cls = (Class<?>) type;

            // here I check if type is a DAO
            if (DAO.class.isAssignableFrom(cls)) {
                ServiceLocatorUtilities.addClasses(serviceLocator, cls);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Application:

```
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {

    public Application() {
        packages("de.jt");
        // register by abstract binder
        register(ApplicationBinder.class);
    }
}
```

ApplicationBinder:

```
public class ApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // bind by jit resolver
        bind(JITResolver.class).to(JITResolver.class);
    }
}
```

the plan is that the JITResolver detects failed injections and returns true for all subclasses of DAO, which will then be created. In this case I want to auto inject the TestDAO. It is bound in the AbstractBinder, which is in return registered in the Application. But when I call the test method, I get the usual exception:

```
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(    requiredType=TestDAO,parent=TestService,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,170935276)
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of de.jt.rest.TestService errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on de.jt.rest.TestService
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The binder needs to be registered as an instance, not a class.

Comment: Also I think you need to say: bind(JITResolver.class).to(JITResolver.class).to(JustInTimeInjectionResolver.class)

Comment: _"because I don't want to add all of my DAO subclasses to my abstract binder manually"_ - You don't have to. You can use annotations. Check out the section "Automatic Service Population" in the [Getting Started](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/getting-started.html). You can inject the ServiceLocator into your ResourceConfig subclass constructor.

Comment: did you get this working?